# Best way to poll a Facebook page/feed for new post?

Tags: c#, java, facebook, selenium, feed

I was going to use selenium webdriver to navigate to a facebook feed and just refresh the page every couple of seconds to check if there is a new post. I will then need to take that post and parse it for data. However this requires my webdriver browser to always to be open. Is there a way to grab the post through the Facebook API or SDK? I really have no experience in this area, and is it possible to do it in Java or C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to realtime updates to the the page, which executes a callback on your server whenever the object changes.

The documentation is grey whether or not you can do this for the `feed` object, but this is one of those features that is being actively developed right now.

[Managing Realtime Update Subscriptions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/managing-realtime-update-subscriptions/)